# Services Module - 500 Internal Server Error When Accessing REST URL

Tags: 7, services, aegir

I created a services endpoint but any time I access the REST URL, e.g. `http://www.mysite.com/endpoint` I get a WSOD and the following in the firebug console:

```
"NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error"
```

No errors in the dblog.  No errors in the apache error log.

The site is hosted on `aegir`.  So as a troubleshooting step I moved the entire drupal files and database to my local machine, hoping that I could step through with a debugger.  Guess what, everything works fine!

I've tried uninstalling modules one by one - no luck

I've tried with a clean drupal install on `aegir` - same 500 error

I'm wondering if anyone can suggest any further troubleshooting steps?

It seems that it could be something to do with the server or aegir configuration.

Comment: Maybe because you're contacting an endpoint without requesting a resource? Do you get a 500 for `http://www.mysite.com/endpoint/user/login`, for example (assuming of course you have that resource enabled)?

Comment: Same problem at `http://www.mysite.com/endpoint/node` - 500 error, resource is enabled.  Usually Services gives a message saying "This endpoint has been setup correctly" when contacting `http://www.mysite.com/endpoint` but getting 500 error and no success message.

Comment: Hmm strange that it works locally, definitely points to some sort of server config issue. Are you using session authentication, and if so are you including the CSRF token header as part of the request? It's been required since v3.4 and caused me a couple of issues very recently

Comment: No session authentication is turned on.  It's got me stumped!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem turned out to be the PHP version on the server.  The Rest Server had a line of code that requires PHP 5.3.

There is an issue at https://drupal.org/node/2003396 and a patch at https://drupal.org/files/ServicesRESTServerFactory.inc_.patch

Installing the patch solved the problem without the need to upgrade the php version on the server